# Find specific pattern and print complete text block using awk or sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk

How can find a specific number in a text block and print the **complete** text block beginning with the key word `"BEGIN"` and ending with `"END"`? Basically this is what my file looks like:

```
BEGIN
A: abc
B: 12345
C: def
END

BEGIN
A: xyz
B: 56789
C: abc
END

BEGIN
A: ghi
B: 56712
C: pqr
END

[...]
```

If I was looking for `'^B: 567'`, I would like to get this output:

```
BEGIN
A: xyz
B: 56789
C: abc
END

BEGIN
A: ghi
B: 56712
C: pqr
END
```

I could use grep here (**`grep -E -B2 -A2 "^B: 567" file`**), but I would like to get a more general solution. I guess *awk* or *sed* might be able to do this!?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/\nB: 567/' file
BEGIN
A: xyz
B: 56789
C: abc
END

BEGIN
A: ghi
B: 56712
C: pqr
END
```

Note the `\n` before `B` to ensure it occurs at the start of a line.This is in place of the `^` start-of-string character you had originally since now each line isn't it's own string. You need to set ORS above to re-insert the blank line between records.

Answer (score 5):

This  might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^BEGIN/{x;d};H;/^END/{x;s/^B: 567/&/mp}' file
```

or this:

```
sed -n '/^BEGIN/!b;:a;$!{N;/\nEND/!ba};/\nB: 567/p' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can undef `RS` to split records in blank lines and check if the string matches in the whole block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } /\nB:[[:space:]]+567/ { print $0 ORS }' infile
```

It yields:

```
BEGIN
A: xyz
B: 56789
C: abc
END 

BEGIN
A: ghi
B: 56712
C: pqr
END
```

Comment: You don't need `$0 ~` in `$0 ~ /B:[[:space:]]+567/` and you should get rid of the comma in `print $0, ORS` so you don't add a space character after every `END` in the output. You really need to anchor the `B` too in case `B: 567` shows up as text on an `A:...` line, for example.

Comment: You really should make it `\nB` not just `B`.

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work:

```
awk -v s='B: 567' '$0~s' RS= file
BEGIN
A: xyz
B: 56789
C: abc
END
BEGIN
A: ghi
B: 56712
C: pqr
END
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Any search string can be passed in this this command.

Comment: That's true, it wouldn't hurt to use the string the OP needs in this example though.

Answer (score 2):

A bit lenghty but the RS-trick was already posted :-)

```
BEGIN {found=0;start=0;i=0}


/BEGIN/ {
    start=1
    delete a
}

/.*567.*/ {found=1}

{
    if (start==1) {
        a[i++]=$0
    }
}

/END/ {
    if (found) {
        for (i in a)
            print a[i]
    }
    found=0
    start=0
    delete a
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f s.awk input
BEGIN
A: xyz
B: 56789
C: abc
END
BEGIN
A: ghi
B: 56712
C: pqr
END
```

Comment: Will produce false matches if 567 appears anywhere on any line and can re-order the text in the output so END comes before BEGIN, or any other permutation, courtesy of `for (i in a)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'if(/56789/){$f=1}
           push @a,$_;
           if(/END/){
              if($f){print join "\n",@a}
           undef @a;$f=0}' your_file
```