# How to print out only certain blocks of text when key/value is something?

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

So if I have something like this, I only want to capture or print out the account info when "Account disabled: False".

```
$ ipa user-find

---------------
2 users matched
---------------
  User login: jpeterson
  First name: john
  Last name: peterson
  Home directory: /home/jpeterson
  Login shell: /bin/sh
  UID: 855800007
  GID: 855800007
  Account disabled: False

  User login: jsmith
  First name: john
  Last name: smith
  Home directory: /home/jsmith
  Login shell: /bin/sh
  UID: 855800004
  GID: 855800004
  Account disabled: True
----------------------------
Number of entries returned 2
----------------------------
```

Expected output would be:

```
  User login: jpeterson
  First name: john
  Last name: peterson
  Home directory: /home/jpeterson
  Login shell: /bin/sh
  UID: 855800007
  GID: 855800007
  Account disabled: False
```

There are multiple accounts with the same keys or attributes.

Maybe I could use an array for this, just not sure.  I haven't tried anything yet except experimenting with `mapfile`.  Putting the file into an array and printing out elements when value equals "False" for key "Account disabled".  But I'm not there yet.

Comment: Are you referring to linux?

Comment: yes, sorry, linux.  should have put more tags

Comment: @cdm, please post sample of expected output along with your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're going about this backwards. `ipa` should have a way to query the database. I've never used it myself but I found [a manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-ipa/) with these examples:

> ```
> ipa user-find foo
> ```
>
> Search for all users with "foo" in either uid, first name, last name, full name, etc. A user with uid "foobar" would match the search criteria.
>
> ```
> ipa user-find foo --first bar
> ```
>
> Same as the previous example, except this time the users first name has to be exactly "bar". A user with uid "foobar" and first name "bar" would match the search criteria.

To get more details, try `ipa help user-find`.

The command you want will probably look like one of these:

```
ipa user-find --disabled False  # Update: this one worked for OP
ipa user-find --account-disabled False
ipa user-find --enabled True
```

That said, if you want to go the text processing route, [you could use `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19257597/4518341).

Comment: I agree. It's an xy problem, and furthermore I would strongly resist the urge to parse output that looks specifically for a set of human eyeballs.

Comment: @Roadowl Good point. Link for OP: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Also related: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple `awk` script:

#### script.awk

```
length() == 1 || /^--*/ {  # if section boundery marker
    if (found == 1) print rec; # print current rec only on found marker
    found = 0; # reset found marker
    rec = ""; # reset rec
    next; # read next line
}
/Account disabled: True/ {found = 1;} # if on disabled account, set found marker
{rec = rec $0 ORS} # accumulate current line into rec
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

#### output:

```
  User login: jsmith
  First name: john
  Last name: smith
  Home directory: /home/jsmith
  Login shell: /bin/sh
  UID: 855800004
  GID: 855800004
  Account disabled: True
```

Comment: That awk script doesn't seem to work.