# Find pattern in file and print every xth occurrence to another file

Tags: file, awk, sed, file-io

I have a very large file that is similar to the snippet below.  The snippet shows three blocks of data.  They are from three distinct time steps (i).

```
6 # <--This is the same for all data blocks (i.e., always 6 rows of data)
i =        0, time =        0.000, k =      9000000000000
X        -7.6415350292        6.0494971539        8.1919697993
Y        -6.6418362233        5.9231018862        8.4056822626
Y        -8.0518670684        6.3158684817        9.0061271154
X        26.8252967820       20.4661074967       17.8025744066
Y        26.4477411207       20.4071029058       16.9121571912
Y        26.4399648474       21.2950722068       18.1009273227
6
i =        1, time =        0.500, k =      2500000000000
X        -6.2423192714       -1.5704681396       -9.5648670474
Y        -5.4925100813       -1.6522059045       -8.9030589772
Y        -6.7765278574       -2.3616512405       -9.4776648590
X         4.1248924594       27.8487302083      -17.5400886312
Y         4.1238657681       26.9869907778      -17.9727402579
Y         5.0750649402       28.1292768156      -17.6848507559
6
i =        2, time =        1.000, k =      3945000000000
X        19.0090162215       -5.9338939011        6.1931167954
Y        18.4748060757       -6.4905073540        5.6656446036
Y        19.2825591449       -6.4479943255        7.0179774953
X        11.0203415273       34.6029396705        2.7220660957
Y        11.1184002007       34.8398120338        1.8089008500
Y        10.3349649622       33.9509485292        2.5605794622
```

1. **I would like to print every 100th data block to a new file.**

The answer from @potong at the link below looks promising (if I understand, the other answers depend on a blank line between the data blocks and I don't have one).  I have managed to use it to print every distinct block to its own file.  But I end up with too many files.  If anyone knows how to adapt potong's method so that it only works on every xth block, I would be very grateful for a hint.

[Find specific pattern and print complete text block using awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257597/find-specific-pattern-and-print-complete-text-block-using-awk-or-sed)

2. If I do this, I need to make a similar modification to a second (corresponding) file that looks like this:

   ```
   0       0.000       13.6600000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6600000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6600000000          2548
   ```

This is the first row.  The first two columns correspond to `i =        0, time =        0.000` in the first data block above.  **I need to print this row and every xth row to a new file** so that I have two files with data from the same time steps.

I can think of ways put every xth row in a new file, but if there's a way to make sure the first two columns match `i =        0, time =        0.000` above in (1), that would be great to know (so that I don't end up with a mismatch if a row has failed to print or a time step has been repeated in the file).

I have added an "Awk" tag because it seems like this is something Awk might be able to do, but I am not experienced in Awk.

Comment: this appears (to me) to be 2 different questions; I'd suggest breaking the 2nd question off into a 2nd/separate question or ... remove the 2nd part from this question, wait to see what answers you get, see if you can modify said answer to fit your 2nd issue and *then* if you've having problems create a 2nd question ... ???

Comment: for the 1st issue, please update the question with more details on how to determine the new file names

Comment: Don't show 3 blocks and say you want every 100th block written to a new file as you can't show that and we can't test it. Instead create a [mcve] with, say, 7 **shorter** blocks (e.g. 3 lines per block instead of 8), tell us you want every 3rd block written to a new file instead of every 100th, and then include the expected output file(s). That will clarify your requirements and gives us something we can copy/paste to test with and you can just tweak the answer if necessary later, e.g. to change 3 to 100.

Comment: So do you want to just print `i` and `time` for every 100th block, to a a new (empty) file? As well as, print every 100th block in full, separately? I have a simple awk solution for every 100th block in full, but I'm unsure what exactly you need in the other file. Just two columns?

Comment: @markp-fuso, sorry for the delayed response (power cut).  Thank you for your help.  The new file names could be of the corresponding time step.  I.e., "0, 1, 2, ..."  However, I see you have left an answer, so I will go through that first before responding further here and potentially confusing everyone.

Comment: @dan, sorry I wasn't clear.  For (2) of my question, I would like an entire row printed to a new file.  So the same thing as the original file, except only every xth row.  For (1) of my question, I would like an entire block of data for every xth block of data printed to a new file and the time step needs to match the one printed to the first file.  If this is confusing, please feel free to let me know and I can perhaps split the question as another commenter suggested.  I didn't do that because it's important the data in the two new files match as far as the time step.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** only addressing OP's first requirement of printing every 100th block to a separate/new file ...

Assumptions:

- each block consists of 8 lines (the standalone `6`, the `i = ...` line, and 6 data lines)
- each 8-line block of interest to be dumped to a separate output file
- output file name format: `block.<block_count>.dat` (OP can change per requirement)

Sample data:

```
$ cat  block.dat
6 # block #1
i =        0, time =        0.000, k =      9000000000000
X        -7.6415350292        6.0494971539        8.1919697993
Y        -6.6418362233        5.9231018862        8.4056822626
Y        -8.0518670684        6.3158684817        9.0061271154
X        26.8252967820       20.4661074967       17.8025744066
Y        26.4477411207       20.4071029058       16.9121571912
Y        26.4399648474       21.2950722068       18.1009273227
6 # block #2
i =        1, time =        0.500, k =      2500000000000
X        -6.2423192714       -1.5704681396       -9.5648670474
Y        -5.4925100813       -1.6522059045       -8.9030589772
Y        -6.7765278574       -2.3616512405       -9.4776648590
X         4.1248924594       27.8487302083      -17.5400886312
Y         4.1238657681       26.9869907778      -17.9727402579
Y         5.0750649402       28.1292768156      -17.6848507559
6 # block #3
i =        2, time =        1.000, k =      3945000000000
X        19.0090162215       -5.9338939011        6.1931167954
Y        18.4748060757       -6.4905073540        5.6656446036
Y        19.2825591449       -6.4479943255        7.0179774953
X        11.0203415273       34.6029396705        2.7220660957
Y        11.1184002007       34.8398120338        1.8089008500
Y        10.3349649622       33.9509485292        2.5605794622
6 # block #4
i =        2, time =        1.000, k =      3945000000000
X        19.0090162215       -5.9338939011        6.1931167954
Y        18.4748060757       -6.4905073540        5.6656446036
Y        19.2825591449       -6.4479943255        7.0179774953
X        11.0203415273       34.6029396705        2.7220660957
Y        11.1184002007       34.8398120338        1.8089008500
Y        10.3349649622       33.9509485292        2.5605794622
```

One `awk` idea to print out every `xth` block

```
x=2                         # set to 100 per OP's requirement

awk -v x="${x}" '
$1 == "6"    { count++ }
!(count % x) { print > "block." count ".dat"}
' block.dat
```

This generates:

```
for f in block.*.dat
do
    echo "########### $f"
    cat $f
done

########### block.2.dat
6 # block #2
i =        1, time =        0.500, k =      2500000000000
X        -6.2423192714       -1.5704681396       -9.5648670474
Y        -5.4925100813       -1.6522059045       -8.9030589772
Y        -6.7765278574       -2.3616512405       -9.4776648590
X         4.1248924594       27.8487302083      -17.5400886312
Y         4.1238657681       26.9869907778      -17.9727402579
Y         5.0750649402       28.1292768156      -17.6848507559
########### block.4.dat
6 # block #4
i =        2, time =        1.000, k =      3945000000000
X        19.0090162215       -5.9338939011        6.1931167954
Y        18.4748060757       -6.4905073540        5.6656446036
Y        19.2825591449       -6.4479943255        7.0179774953
X        11.0203415273       34.6029396705        2.7220660957
Y        11.1184002007       34.8398120338        1.8089008500
Y        10.3349649622       33.9509485292        2.5605794622
```

Comment: I'm getting: awk -v x='${x}' ' (^ syntax error) and awk -v x='${x}' ' (^ invalid char ''' in expression).  I'm looking for solutions now and it seems like it could be a Linux vs Windows thing.  Don't feel like you have to solve it but I just thought I'd mention it in case you have ever seen it.  Thank you.

Comment: did you cut-n-paste directly from my answer, or did you manually type the code into your script? also, what do you get when you run `awk --version`? if you can't get it working I suggest you update the question (at the end) with an exact copy of the code you're running, the error message, and the output from `awk --version`

Comment: I did cut and paste at first!  Then I manually typed everything out and get the same error.  My Awk version is 4.0.2 (at an external machine).

Comment: did you make sure to set a value for the OS/bash variable `x`? (`x=2` in the sample - above)

Comment: @markpfuso, thanks for mentioning that.  Yes I did.  Not to worry.  I'll continue in the morning.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much, @markpfuso.  I got it working.  Unfortunately, someone has closed the question but I hope you will still get credit.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/^6/{:a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/8;Ta;x;s/^/x/;/x{100}/{z;x;p;x};x}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and on extended regexp `-nE`.

Starting with a line that begins with `6`, gather up 8 lines and then swap to the hold space, increment a counter, test the counter for the required occurrence (in this case 100) and if so, zero the counter, swap back to the pattern space, print it, and return to the hold space. In all situations return to the pattern space.

N.B. The number of lines in a record (in this case 8) can be changed as well as the output record number (in this case 100).

Comment: thanks a lot for that.  I can't get it to work but will keep trying.  No doubt a silly mistake I'm making somewhere.  I appreciate your time.  I'm practicing my sed and Awk but it's a slow process!

Comment: Thank you, @potang.  I figured out my problem and got it working.